# Expresion regular para django url con slug que contiene "/"

Tags: python, django, regex, django-models, django-urls

La idea es crear una expresion regular para configurar la url

Tengo 2 modelos, categoria y articulos.
El modelo articulo tiene un FK a categoria y el slug hacce el join correctamente slug(categoria)/slug(articulo).
Yo quiero usar en la url el separador "/" si uso cualquier otro ejemplo "-" no tengo problemas.

**MODELOS**

```
class Categoria(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, null=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre


class Articulo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
    descripcion = models.TextField(blank=True)
    precio= models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 2, default=0.00, max_digits = 12)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria)
    destacado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    orden = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='article_img', blank=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='article_img', blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='article_img', blank=True)
    image4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='article_img', blank=True)
    image5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='article_img', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = '/'.join((slugify(self.categoria).lower().replace(' ','_'), slugify(self.nombre))).lower().replace(' ','_')
        super(Articulo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug
```

**URL**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', ArticleList.as_view(), name='list'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

**ERROR**

```
> Page not found (404)
> Request Method:   GET
> Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/tienda/ortopedia/muletas-de-aluminio
> Using the URLconf defined in sinam.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:  
> ^tienda/ ^$ [name='list']  
> ^tienda/ ^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$ [name='detail']  
> ^admin/
```

Answer (score 1):

Me pasaron la solucion por otro foro.

**Correcto:**

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[/\w-]+)/$', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Comment: Me alegra que consiguieras la solucion. Pero intenta adecuar la respuesta usando la guia [answer]. Ah y este sitio no es un foro ;)